# Django main-app's urls.py can't import *app*.views

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to set up my "home" page for the django project. 
For some reason, my main app is not able to import the views.py, when I try that line in shell, it works without a problem. any ideas as to what am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
Could not import BoxItWebservice.views.Home.as_view(). Parent module BoxItWebservice.views.Home does not exist.
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
#from BoxItWebservice import views

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'BoxItWebservice.views.Home.as_view()', name='home'),
    ##url(r'^login/', 'BoxItWebservice.views.Login.as_view()', name='login'),
    # url(r'^BoxItWebservice/', include('BoxItWebservice.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^files/', include('fileservice.urls', namespace="files")),
    url(r'^manage/', include('filesfrontend.urls', namespace="manage")),
    (r'', include('tokenapi.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import View, TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core import urlresolvers

#django token_api
from tokenapi.decorators import token_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

#Main
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    @login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def dispatch(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super(Home, self).dispatch(*args,**kwargs)
'''
class Login(View):
    """docstring for Login"""
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py fix it like that:

```
from BoxItWebservice.views import Home
...
url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
...
```

Further reference: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: @Alex_Parakhnevich I get "No module named Home" error

Comment: @YoavSchwartz you should provide the legitimate import path for your Home view, it depends on your project's structure.

Comment: urls.py and views.py are in the same folder and the same patters seems to work for every other app

Comment: Try relative import then: `from .views import Home`

Comment: Same error, this is really weird, the shell has not problem importing, just this particular urls.py.

Comment: Thx for all the answers man, It turns out the mistake was really stupid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, and the mistake is really stupid, I wrote `'BoxItWebservice.views.Home.as_view()'` and I have no idea why I decided to add ''. Once I removed them everything worked.